# Websphere 6.1 publish failed .. error :CNTR0146E

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.0

When publishing my application on `Websphere 6.1`, publish fails with the following error :

```
The application cannot start:  ApplicationEAR
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.metadata.MetaDataException: CNTR0146E: The META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml bindings file contained in the MyApplicationEJB.jar module has a configuration error at line number: -1, column number: -1.
com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3829)
com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:172)
com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:306)
com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:581)
com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:832)
com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:950)
com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1495)
com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4104)
com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4202)
com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:245)
..........
```

`ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<session name="PendingNotificationProcessor">
    <resource-ref name="PendingNotificationQueueCF"
        binding-name="jms/PendingNotificationQueueFactory"></resource-ref>
    <resource-ref name="PendingNotificationQueue"
        binding-name="jms/PendingNotificationQueue"></resource-ref>
</session>

<session name="NotificationSender" simple-binding-name="ejb/NotificationSender">
</session>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

Any Advice ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` binding file for errors in RAD.

Comment: What is the latest fixpack for 6.1 server.

Comment: Can you share you binding file?

Comment: Please update your environment because it is too old.

Comment: You should always keep you environment updated to latest fixpacks.  There is another idea - clean your server.  Stop it; delete all from wstemp directory and then try to deploy again.

Comment: i have cleaned the server before posting this question :(

Comment: Another question to you how do you assemble application?

Comment: my application was running on the same environment
i haven't edited anything , 
just left it for two weeks to work on WAS 7.0 (with another app in another workspace)

Comment: Maybe problem is that you rebuild your application under WAS7 environment. Basically you should export your application from eclipse in order to install to you environment - this action will create build your application, create default binding and create ear.

Comment: I tried this suggestion and also the ear couldn't be started with the same error

Comment: How do you deploy your application?